# Does disallowing some concurrent GET requests violate RFC 2616 (safety/idempotency)?

Tags: http, concurrency, get, rfc2616

I'm currently debating the question on wether disallowing concurrent GET requests on a given resource constitutes a violation of RFC 2616 (especially the idempotency and safety properties required for the GET method, §9.1).

For instance; if my server receives a 
GET /data/?dataId=123456 
twice simultaneously, would you consider it a violation of safety or idempotency that one or both requests returns an error message ?

As per my understanding, the RFC specifies that the same request should yield the same result when called again.
I haven't seen however anything about what behaviours are acceptable regarding concurrent requests.

My feeling is that disallowing concurrent GET access (on a given resource, not as a general rule of course) does not constitute a violation of the RFC.
Returning a 423 response code, or a 500 (although not very elegant), or even a 429 or a 420 (although the meaning is slightly different) seems acceptable to me.

I would like to know however if there are valid arguments proving that the RFC denies this position.

Thanks in advance / Best Regards

Comment: it's done on a daily basis by file sharing services - one download at a time, or even only one download per URL. same URL used later produces a much different result.

Comment: 423 would be incorrect. 420 is undefined. You could use 429, but I don't fully understand your use case. Why would you *want* to block the request????

Comment: (you'r right about 423) the question is mostly rethorical, but use case is for a GET request that requires access to a resource that doesn't  support concurrent access. I could definitely queue requests until the resource is freed, but I was wondering about the RFC compliance in case I decide not to do so, and just return an error code (which is what we currently do since in our case concurrent access do not normally happen)

Comment: (420 is the response code used by twitter API to limit the rate of queries)

Answer (score 0):

### [9.1.1 Safe Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods **SHOULD NOT** have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval.

Blocking a resource might qualify as an action other than retrieval. But the wording [**SHOULD NOT**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) definitely allows you to do so! You could rephrase it to: it's not recommended, but it's valid. If the user doesn't even know that he is causing that side effect it's even better:

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; [..] The important distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects.

### [9.1.2 Idempotent Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2)

> A **sequence** that never has side effects is idempotent, by definition (provided that **no concurrent operations** are being executed on the same set of resources).

The only side effect your implementation has is blocking concurrent requests. No side effects for sequential requests.
I understand that quoted passage that it is no requirement for 9.1.2 to be side effect free on concurrent requests. So you get a *valid* for 9.1.2 from me.

BTW. I would answer with a [503 Service Unavailable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4) together with a [Retry-After](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37) header.

Answer (score 0):

Operationally, your server is allowed to do whatever it likes regarding protecting its resources from attacks.

That said, disallowing *any* concurrent GETs to a resource will surprise many clients, to put it mildly.